# Request Object Params value can't be passed directly to object Render?

Tags: node.js, express

When I use a req.param value in a res.render, the view loads correctly but then I also get an error (Error: Cannot find module 'css').

I am using Node / Express. My route includes a param value that the controller will use to identify the correct view to render.

This code (next few lines) loads the correct view, but it also gives a console error (see below):

---My Route:

```
 router.get('/go/:user_homePage',controller_login.redirectHomepage);
```

---From My Controller:

```
 exports.redirectHomepage = function(req,res){
     res.render(req.params.user_homePage);  
 }
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:  My redirectHomepage is also doing some other stuff. That is why I am using the route (with param) to call the view this way.

A GET request like this: " /go/Shipping_Department " DOES load the correct view (Shipping_Department.ejs), but it also sends a console error ( Error: Cannot find module 'css').

When I change my controller function to this (see next few lines), I still get the correct view rendered and no console error.:

```
 exports.redirectHomepage = function(req,res){
     var l_goto_homepage = req.params.user_homePage;

     switch(l_goto_homepage) {
           case "Customer":
                var hPage = "Customer_1";
                break;
           case "Shipping_Department":
                var hPage = "Shipping_Department";
                break;
     }
     res.render(hPage);  
 }
```

Why would first assigning the req.param value to a variable (l_got_homepage) make a difference? Isn't req.params.user_homePage already a string value?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the console error:

```
 [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
 [nodemon] starting `node main.js`
 web_proj2 server is running
 Error: Cannot find module 'css'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
     at new View (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
     at Function.render (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
     at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
     at exports.redirectHomepage (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\controllers\controller_login.js:281:7)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
     at next (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Bill\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to a "css" module in the code you've shared. Where is that coming from? Please edit your question to include the full text and stack trace of the error message.

Comment: Hi Jordan. Thank you for responding. The only possible source of the "css" reference (that I can see) is the first line of my Shipping_Department.ejs template . It is a link my style sheet ( <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css"> ).   I will add the stack trace.

Comment: This just occurred to me.  My style sheet (mycss.css) is located in a static folder (/public).  I referenced this static folder in my main.js file but NOT in the controller_login.js file.  BUT... the page DOES LOAD with the correct styles (from mycss.css) before throwing the console error, so I can't see how this can then be a link reference error.

Comment: ...and there are no console errors by simply assigning the req.params value to an interim variable first.

Comment: You hear about threads that die unresolved. You just never think it will happen to you.

Comment: To anyone who finds this thread because they are seeing the same problem, here is what I have found.  My redirect is working, but it is calling the route multiple times. It is calling the route for each linked item in my view (style sheet, javascript link, etc). I do not know why.